# How to make a synchronous http request on a node server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, http

I have a node web server with several api endpoints. One of those endpoints needs to make a request to another server in order to assemble its own response. I've seen a few different answers with links to libraries that allow purely synchronous web requests, but they're all associated with warnings that say not to use them in production.

Here is an example of what my server request handler looks like:

```
app.get('/my_api_endpoint', function (req, res) {

    // Need to get data from other webservice using data 
    // from this request.
    data = request_to_other_web_service(req.params.some_value);

    res.status(200);
    res.send("This is the " + data);
    res.end();

});
```

Is there a standard pattern for handling requests like this?

Comment: checkout [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), is a promise-based javascript http client.

Comment: No node.js server should EVER do synchronous I/O in any real time request handler.  Never.  It would absolutely ruin the scalability of your server.  Instead, learn how to do asynchronous I/O properly.  For us to show you how to do this request to this other web service, you would have to show us the details of that request and then we could show you the specific detail for how to do it properly.

Comment: As it stands now, you're asking for something that node.js isn't built to do and should never be done from any node.js request handler.  So, the question needs to be rephrased to express the problem you're trying to solve, not the specific solution (synchronous I/O) that you seem to want.  That's not the right direction for a solution.  What you have posted is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you've asked a question about your proposed solution direction rather than asking us to help you solve the actual problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 Maybe synchronous was the wrong word. What I mean is that I *need* the response from the other web service before I formulate the response from my web service.  I don't think I need to provide any details of the other request other than it's a standard http request with a json response that my web service needs to work.  It's not really clear why synchronous I/O is so terrible (considering lots of other frameworks and languages use synchronous I/O in their  web frameworks).  Even if the evaluation is technically "asynchronous" it still needs to block my response until it completes.

Comment: Well, you said "synchronous".  That was apparently the wrong word because that's what I reacted to. You don't need anything to block. You just finish your response in the asynchronous callback.  There's no blocking of anything. There's no synchronous networking.  You just need to learn how to program with asynchronous I/O in node.js where you handle the response in a callback.  You can either use regular async callbacks or you can use a promise interface.  In both you're handling the response and any code that wants to use it in a callback.  That's what you need to learn in node.js/Javascript.

Comment: Keep in mind that the word "synchronous" has a very specific meaning in node.js - something that blocks the entire intrepreter such as `fs.readFileSync()`.  So, please don't use it if that specific meaning is not what you meant. Even when using `await` to "wait" for a promise which may appear to block, it actually causes your function to return immediately and lots of other code can then run.  There is no actual blocking of the interpreter.  With `await` your function execution is suspended until the promise you are awaiting resolves or rejects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are getting errors/warnings when trying to synchronously call an HTTP request is that from the get-go node.js was built with the core philosophy of callbacks & the event loop. If you are trying to write asynchronous code in a synchronous way... May i point you in the direction of async/await. You could you use `npm install node-fetch`

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

app.get('/my_api_endpoint', async function (req, res) {

    // Need to get data from other webservice using data 
    // from this request.
    data = await fetch("http://...");

    res.status(200);
    res.send("This is the " + data);
    res.end();

});
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed.  I used axios, but the async/await syntax worked.

Answer (score 1):

In general all javascript libraries/frameworks are friendly to non-synchronous operations. Those that are not will be ignored by the community. Express already allow you to perform asynchronous operations.

Have you ever wondered why express requires you to "return" responses by calling methods on `res` instead of simply returning?:

```
// frameworks in some other languages:

@Path("/my_api_endpoint")
Response myEndpoint() {
    data = request_to_other_web_service(some_value);
    return data; // Javascript frameworks don't use returns!!
}
```

It is because all javascript web frameworks are async friendly. The reason you use a callback (a function that you call back at some later time) to return from a route is because you can call functions inside other functions. In Express you call `res.send()` **after** you've performed async operations. How you do it depends on the API you're using:

API that accepts a callback:

```
app.get('/my_api_endpoint', function (req, res, next) {
    request(req.params.some_value, function (error, data) {
        if (!error) {
            res.status(200);
            res.send("This is the " + data);
        }
        else {
            next(error);
        }
    }
});
```

API that returns a promise:

```
app.get('/my_api_endpoint', function (req, res, next) {
    request(req.params.some_value)
        .then(function (data) {
            res.status(200);
            res.send("This is the " + data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            next(error);
        });
});
```

Using async/await with API that returns a promise:

```
app.get('/my_api_endpoint', async function (req, res, next) {
    try {
        let data = await request(req.params.some_value)
        res.status(200);
        res.send("This is the " + data);
    }
    catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
});
```

Stream based API:

```
app.get('/my_api_endpoint', async function (req, res, next) {
    let dataStream = request(req.params.some_value);
    let buffer = "";

    dataStream.on('data', function (data) {
        buffer += data.toString('utf8');
    });

    dataStream.on('end', function () {
        res.status(200);
        res.send("This is the " + buffer);
    });

    dataStream.on('error', function () {
        next("Stream error");
    });

});
```

Express can handle any asynchronous program flow.